# Cannot define MAX value for IntType in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

Why this doesn't work in GCC 4.5.1

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits.h>//for INT_MIN
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define UNIVERSAL_INT_MAX LLONG_MAX
#define UNIVERSAL_INT_MIN LLONG_MIN
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define UNIVERSAL_INT_MAX LONG_LONG_MAX  
#define UNIVERSAL_INT_MIN LONG_LONG_MIN
#endif
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << UNIVERSAL_INT_MAX << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Error I'm getting:

```
"main.cpp|24|error: 'LONG_LONG_MAX' was not declared in this scope"
```

**EDIT**

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define UNIVERSAL_INT_MAX ( ( 1ULL << numeric_limits< long long >::digits ) - 1 )
#define UNIVERSAL_INT_MAX_plus_three (UNIVERSAL_INT_MAX + 3)
#endif
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << UNIVERSAL_INT_MAX << '\n';
    cout << "Huhh?: " << UNIVERSAL_INT_MAX_plus_three << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you compile with a `-std=xxx` option, where xxx supports `long long`?

Comment: Again, if you need a compile time constant, state it in the question rather than letting others [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529431/cannot-define-max-value-for-inttype-in-gcc/5529453#5529453). It is not like this is the first time you ask for different variations of the same thing and fail to provide a complete question.

Answer (score 6):

`long long` is nonstandard so `LONG_LONG_MAX` is nonstandard.

Better to use the C++ mechanism `numeric_limits< long long >::max()`, which is in `<limits>`.

`long long` is still nonstandard, but if the compiler implements it, this is guaranteed to work.

EDIT: You can achieve the same thing as a compile-time constant using

```
( ( 1ULL << numeric_limits< long long >::digits ) - 1 )
```

Comment: care to elaborate on that trick? It's interesting, but I can't convince myself it's truly portable from a quick read.

Comment: @Potatoswatter need compile-time constant

Comment: @awoodland: This assumes that `long long` is a signed, binary type and `unsigned long long` exists and has literals ending `ULL`. So no, it's not perfectly portable, but it's at least better than outright assuming the value is 2^63 - 1.

Comment: @Potatoswatter but the funny thing is that those MACROS are defined in GCC headers (in <limits.h>).

Comment: @There: Like I said to @awoodland, this isn't terribly portable. When it comes to `min`, there's no way to compute it without making an assumption about the underlying number system: signed magnitude or two's complement. So… you can use an assumption (pick an assumption) and a little creativity.

Comment: @There: `<limits>` and `<limits.h>` are completely separate things. The former is C++ and the latter is plain C.

Comment: @There: The expression returns the value in an unsigned type. So what?

Comment: @Potatoswatter if 1ULL << numeric_limits< long long >::digits ) - 1 returns 9223372036854775807 and that is supposed to be max value how adding 3 to it makes it 9223372036854775810? Judging by this it seems to me that what you've showed doesn't returns max value (because if it would adding even one would cause overflow), isn't that so?

Comment: @There: It is the maximum value of a `signed long long`. Because that value is returned as an `unsigned long long`, you can still add three. That really is no longer a possible value of `signed long long`. If you want, you can `static_cast` it back to a `signed long long`, but there isn't an apparent reason to do so. `numeric_limits<char>::max() + 3` is `131` because of integral promotion, but so what?

Comment: @Potatoswatter but to what type is "your" case promoted if add to it 3?

Comment: @There: The macro is an `unsigned long long`, and so is the result.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is C++ why not use std::numeric_liimts?

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I need compile time constants

Answer (score 2):

Try `LLONG_MAX`: it's as non-standard as long long, but it's compile-time

Comment: @Ronald no go, unfortunately.

Comment: and why is that a no go? your installation doesn't have it? your preproc defs hide it?

Comment: @Ronald I've tried and I'm getting the same error as with LONG_LONG_MAX - undefined - but I don't understand this because both these "definitions" are defined in limits.h in GCC.

Comment: OK, in that case, your preproc defs are hiding it. My G++ (4.4.3) accepts your code without problem.

Comment: In limits.h, it seems to define `LLONG_MAX` to `__LONG_LONG_MAX__` Have you tried that one?

Comment: @Ronald yes, __LONG_LONG_MAX__ works but __LONG_LONG_MIN__ doesn't why?

Comment: `LLONG_MIN` is `-__LONG_LONG_MAX__-1LL`, IIRC, so long long min is defined as a function of long long max